# How to take bean definition out of xml file?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following *app-context.xml* file:

```
<bean id="buttonPanel" class="todo.ui.BoxLayoutPanel" init-method="init">
    <property name="axis">
      <!--  "0" corresponds to BoxLayout.X_AXIS -->
      <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property name="panelComponents">
      <list>
        <ref bean="deleteButton"/>
        <ref bean="addNewButton"/>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="deleteButton" class="todo.ui.button.ActionListenerButton" 
        init-method="init">
    <property name="actionListener">
      <ref bean="deleteButtonActionListener"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
      <value>Delete</value>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="addNewButton" class="todo.ui.button.ActionListenerButton" 
        init-method="init">
    <property name="actionListener">
      <ref bean="addNewButtonActionListener"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
      <value>Add New</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*ActionListenerButton* looks like this:

```
public class ActionListenerButton extends JButton {
    private ActionListener actionListener;

    public void setActionListener(ActionListener actionListener) {
        this.actionListener = actionListener;
    }

    public ActionListener getActionListener() {
        return actionListener;
    }

    public void init() {
        this.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }
}
```

And the main class contains the following code:

```
String[] contextPaths = new String[] {"pack/app-context.xml"};
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPaths);
```

And I need to take the definitions of *deleteButton* and *addNewButton* out of xml file to code, by means of annotations or any other way.

I tried the following:

```
String[] contextPaths = new String[] {"pack/app-context.xml"};
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextPaths);

AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
GenericBeanDefinition definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
definition.setBeanClass(ActionListenerButton.class);

MutablePropertyValues mpv = new MutablePropertyValues();
mpv.addPropertyValue("actionListener", ctx.getBean("deleteButtonActionListener"));
mpv.addPropertyValue("text", "Delete");
definition.setPropertyValues(mpv);

BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
registry.registerBeanDefinition("deleteButton", definition);
ctx.refresh();
```

But after commenting *deleteButton* bean in *app-context.xml* file:

```
<!-- <bean id="deleteButton" class="todo.ui.button.ActionListenerButton" 
        init-method="init">
    <property name="actionListener">
      <ref bean="deleteButtonActionListener"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
      <value>Delete</value>
    </property>
</bean>  -->
```

I've got the error:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'deleteButton' is defined

How to take the definitions of *deleteButton* and *addNewButton* out of xml file to code, by means of annotations or any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the XML config bean definitions with Java Config bean definitions - sample example below for one of your 2 beans:

```
//ensure this class is discoverable via the component-scan of your app-context.xml
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    //..

    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "deleteButton")
    public ActionListenerButton deleteButton(@Qualifier("deleteButtonActionListener") ???Type deleteButtonActionListener) {
        ActionListenerButton deleteButton = new ActionListenerButton();
        deleteButton.setActionListener(deleteButtonActionListener);
        deleteButton.setText("Delete");
        deleteButton.init();
        return deleteButton;
    }

    //..
}
```

`???Type` is whatever the type of your `deleteButtonActionListener`

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually what I needed!